# In C# PSObject PSPropertyInfo does not return value when PS command-line does return value

Tags: c#, powershell, properties, psobject

In C# I am trying to get the IPAddresses of my computer using the following command (the command works fine in PowerShell and, indeed, shows IP addresses):

In PowerShell:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" -ComputerName $env:ComputerName | Select -Property IPAddress
```

PowerShell Output:

```
{1.2.3.4}
{5.6.7.8}
```

When I turn around and attempt to get the value (stored in results) from the PowerShell command in C# like this:

```
foreach (PSObject obj in results) {

    foreach (PSPropertyInfo objProperties in obj.Properties) {

        string pName = objProperties.Name.ToString(); // returns "IPAddress"

        **string pValue = objProperties.Value.ToString(); // returns "System.String[]" and not an actual IP address**

    }

}
```

**pValue** has a value of "System.String[]" and not the actual IP address value.  But objProperties.Name successfully returns the key-name "IPAddress".

How can I get the actual IP Address instead of "System.String[]"?

Comment: `((string[])objProperties.Value).First()`?

Comment: The documentation for the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration 
CIM class shows that ```IPAddress``` *is* an array of strings (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration) which is why you're getting ```System.String[]``` as the serialised ```ToString``` text for the value. If you want one of the values from the array you'll need to do what @MathiasR.Jessen suggested.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're reading the values via PowerShell and not just using the native C# classes for accessing WMI / CIM?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ah, yes, you're right. My bad. The comment will self-destruct ;)

Comment: @mclayton Just going through some C# tutorials on using PowerShell but none I found really got into what I was trying.

Comment: The answer provided by Mathias R worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix in this scenario, as noted in the comments to the question, is:

```
((string[])objProperties.Value).First()
```